# Firebase postmessage from background to JS listener is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I have a web app that has chat, and I would like to activate audio that I have in my JS when I receive a message when it's in the page or background or at another window tab. So it never plays the audio, only when you are on the window.

This is what I have:
firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
const title = ' - ¡Mensaje Nuevo!';
const options = {
    body: 'conductor: '+payload.data.chofer_id+' - '+payload.data.mensaje,
    icon: '/icono.png',
};

  return self.clients.matchAll().then(all => all.forEach(client => {
    client.postMessage("Responding to ");
   }));

   //return self.registration.showNotification(title, options);
 });
```

my js in my page (here i have my audio to be played):

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('firebase-messaging-sw.js')
                .then(function (reg) {
                    // registration worked
                    console.log('Registration succeeded. Scope is ' + reg.scope);
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    // registration failed
                    console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
                });
        }

        navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function handler(event) {
            console.log('Received a message from service worker: ', event.data);
            $.playSound('Sounds/Tethys.mp3');
        });
```

Comment: i also checked this issue (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/83) from firebase but nothing happens only shows the web notification.

Comment: Interesting. Could you wrap your playSound() call into a try/catch block and do some logging to see if it fails and reports an error code?

Comment: the playsound function works perfectly, it plays the sound when i'm on the web page. even in the logging it's not showing any error.

Comment: Have you tried another browser? Maybe this is eg. a Chrome specific limitation not to interrupt the user or something.

Comment: Did anyone manage to solve this issue ?

Comment: It's been a long time since I worked on this, I don't remember exactly the issue, try playing with the code, I just checked this project, and I can't find any difference from this to make it worked, maybe there is some permission missing.